# How do I properly install bs4 and titlecase packages for use in Apache Airflow?

Tags: python, docker, beautifulsoup, airflow

This is my first post so please bear with me. I am trying to learn how to automate my tasks using Apache Airflow and I am running into a problems whenever I try to import packages such as bs4 and titlecase. Basically, bs4 (For BeautifulSoup) and titlecase can be imported inside my IDE, but whenever I try to run a DAG (which uses bs4 and titlecase) on Airflow, I am getting failed responses:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cEsK.png)

I suspect that this is because bs4 and titlecase failed to properly install when I use Docker. My eventual goal is to automate a web scraping ETL pipeline.

I have tried to install bs4 and titlecase using the tutorial (1st method) here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UepvC9X4HY&t=285s

The problem is that the installation process worked according to the video, except the last part, which is the checking for the bs4 version, of which I am getting a module not found error:
[Module Not Found Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOdjq.png)

To this end, how do I properly install bs4 inside my Docker environment?

Thank you!

Comment: You will have to make sure the packages are installed in the Python environment where your scraping code is getting executed i.e. Airflow worker

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for Astronomer. If you're just using this for learning, I recommend using the free and open source [Astro CLI](https://docs.astronomer.io/astro/cli/overview). Run `astro dev init` in a new directory, then add `bs4` and `titlecase` to the requirements.txt file, then run `astro dev start` and voila.